# When I try to compile perl script in Padre, it has no response at all

Tags: perl, padre

I have a question about Padre. When I try to compile a hello world perl script, it has no response at all. The Padre can still be running. And also, if try to start debugger, the Padre will halt.  I even reinstall Padre it for several times but still. Do you know how to resolve this? Thanks very much.

Comment: The padre version is 0.94 within Dwim5.14.21. And I also have tested my perl scripts in commands line, it's ok.
For what I have seen and test, it has something to do with ActivePerl. When ActivePerl is not installed, Padre is OK. So I tried to use PPM to install Win32-GUI. Then it has some confilction with WideStudio and Pedro. So I resinstall it for many times. Then this bug shows up. I can run script any more.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't use Windows for programming if I can avoid it, but I don't think you need to ActivePerl and PPM to install Win32-GUI. You should be able to navigate to your Strawberry Perl directory within a Windows prompt and use `cpan` to install modules.

Comment: Two points: (1) It's really hard to say anything without your example script in hand. (2) If you installed Padre with Dwim, then you should not use ActivePerl. If you need to install modules, use the cpan command-line tool.

Answer (score 5):

At times Padre has issue in Launching the window to show the output.

Go to Tools -> Preferences -> uncheck "Use External Window for execution"

also make sure the bin you want to use is the first one in Path variable

Comment: helps also for crashing when trying to run debugger

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue - Padre IDE would come up, could load programs which were recognized by syntax highlighting as Perl, but Run/F5 didn't run script and debug would crash Padre.

Workaround found was to uninstall Padre (version was from http://padre.perlide.org/download.html), install Strawberry Perl (http://strawberryperl.com/) version 5.14.2.1 (default), and build Padre via cpan ( "C:>cpan Padre" per http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/DownloadCPAN).

Running on Windows XP.

Other note, had to manually correct my PATH environment variable as with some of the installs and uninstalls, I had unneeded directories and one truncated directory set.

Answer (score 0):

Which Perl are you using (ActivePerl or DWIM)?

(There is a way to install Padre with Active Perl).

When you go (without a debugger) "perl -v", what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

disable the 'enable perl beginner mode' in preference > language perl 5

If IDE still crashes on running the code, the best solution is to check the 'use external window' in the above window. Now Padre works fine compiling simple hello world as well as hello gtk scripts.